# Connection Pooling in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I read [an article](http://morewally.com/cs/blogs/wallym/archive/2010/11/01/why-oh-why-is-pooling-turned-off-in-entity-framework-4-0-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) about Connection pooling in Entity Framework4, it said that :

> connection pooling is OFF in EF4 by default!

I want to know Connection pooling is ON in Entity Framework6 by default? if it's OFF, how can turn it ON?

Comment: Maybe link the article as well?

Comment: This is the link : [link](http://morewally.com/cs/blogs/wallym/archive/2010/11/01/why-oh-why-is-pooling-turned-off-in-entity-framework-4-0-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is NOT turned off by default. You can try it yourself, simply create a new Entity Model and check the connection string it produces. Not sure how Mr. McClure got to his problem, but it is not the standard behavior. I've tested it with VS 2012 and 2013. I'm really not sure why would VS 2010 he was using behave differently, but who knows. The older version of VS might be the cause...

Anyway, the fix for such behavior would be to simply delete the part that says `Pooling=False;`